# Was this created with using UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, interface-builder

Can the interface in this picture be created using UITableView?
[image]

Comment: Yes.  It's a table view with sections and a custom cell that has a righthand image and two labels

Comment: @danh and Santa Claus thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is creted using `tableView` with custom cells and having section with two lablels.If you need how to build custom cells than this may help http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/